# Как передать данные id в modal окно

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

У меня есть код который выводить записи и у каждой записи есть кнопка edit.
По нажатию которой должно открываться модальное окно .Затем через ajax выбирать данные записи.Но как передать id в js при нажатии на кнопку.и отобразить в модальном окне.

```
 @foreach($places as $place)
                    <div class="item row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 item-img">
                            <img src="{{asset('storage/company/place/'.$place->photo)}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-7 item-info">
                            <h2 class="item-info__name">{{$place->type}}</h2>
                            <p class="item-info__price">
                                <strong>{{$place->price}}</strong> руб
                                <span class="item-info__price_type">финская</span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="item-info__descr">
                               {{$place->description}}
                            </p>
                            <div class="item-info__feature">
                                <img src="assets/img/main/features/background-house-item-01-min.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/main/features/turkey-icons-realistic-min.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/main/features/a5333ba4787528fd4712688d7dddab86-min.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/main/features/85827548-isometric-people-diving-into-water-in-to-the-swimming-pool-diver-male-swimmer-that-jumping-and-divin-min.jpg">
                                <img src="assets/img/main/features/stock-vector-young-woman-on-massage-table-in-spa-salon-isolated-on-white-background-672541642-min.png">
                                <img src="assets/img/main/features/depositphotos_173139402-stock-illustration-realistic-microphone-icon-vector-min.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 item-location">
                            <a href="#" class="info__photo_del" title="Удалить"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                            <a href="#" class="info__photo_edit"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#place_form" title="Редактировать"><i
                                    class="fas fa-pen-alt"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: Добавьте атрибут `data-id=` к кнопке, а в js его исполльзуете

Comment: а как получить дата id

Comment: А где сейчас этот id есть?